# Media uploads to wordpress yield blank or broken image link, and the file not there after switching from multisite to single site

Tags: wordpress

I have recently changed a site from multisite to single site by changing and commenting the parameters in the `wp-config.php`.

After doing so I cannot upload any file into the media library.
The upload seems to go but the file does not get displayed (broken image link appears).

Does anyone know what is the root cause of this issue?

I have tried...

- Changing file and directory permissions.
- Changing file and directory ownership.
- Disabling caching plugins.

The images still upload but are not physically there in the appropriate directory.

Comment: Some steps you could take to debug - 1. Go to wp-admin/options.php and check your upload path 2. Enable errors and check your php error log or inspect ajax response in the network tab on chrome the when doing an upload

Comment: thank you @pierdevara,
I have tried those but still did not work. There were no AJAX errors nor PHP errors. The team have decided to do a fresh installation and an XML import.
Will see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

I had to change the "Store uploads in this folder" setting in Dashboard -> Settings -> Media  Which had not been updated after following the other standard steps for changing the directory of our site.

Comment: Thank you. Those steps were done. I think another method was employed because I no longer work on that project.